# YOLOv5 - Concat() issue. RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, yolov5

The code:

```
import torch

yolo_ = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5x', pretrained=True, force_reload=True)
yolo_(torch.rand((2,3,1280,720)))
```

Returns:

```
RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1. Expected size 46 but got size 45 for tensor number 1 in the list.
```

from:

```
~/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/models/common.py in forward(self, x)
    310 
    311     def forward(self, x):
--> 312         return torch.cat(x, self.d)
```

This issue was raised while trying to integrate yolo in a larger classifier. I narrow it down to the code above. As far as I can tell, this error is within the model. I tried different input shapes but get the same result. I also tried yolo5s, same deal. Here is the yolo github code where the error originates from. https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/models/common.py

The concatenation is done on a list `x` of 2 tensors:

```
x[0].shape=
torch.Size([2, 640, 80, 46])
x[1].shape=
torch.Size([2, 640, 80, 45])
```

Why is this happening?
Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I used this ref https://docs.ultralytics.com/yolov5/tutorials/pytorch_hub_model_loading/#detailed-example. Reshaping the input and passing a numpy array instead of a tensor worked. ```yolo_(torch.rand((1280,720,3,2)).numpy())```

Result:
```YOLOv5 <class 'models.common.Detections'> instance
 image 1/1: 1280x720 (no detections)
Speed: 7.1ms pre-process, 31.9ms inference, 1.0ms NMS per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 384)
```

If anyone knows why we need a numpy, would be great to know for the future. Looking forward to comments.

Comment: Actually, it works without reshaping. Passing a numpy array is enough.

Answer (score 0):

The input has to be a tensor still as the torch dataloader presents tensors to the model during training and not numpy arrays.